# Is java.lang.Math.max(int a, int b) thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am wondering whether the static method `java.lang.Math.max(int a, int b)` is thread safe?

If it is not thread safe, could you explain the situation where this method gives wrong output due to concurrent access of to multiple threads, with a piece of code?

Comment: You have over 30 questions without an accepted answer. +1 for asking an answerable question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey but not a real question, so -1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only get thread safety issues from concurrent access of shared state where at least one thread modifies the state.

`Math.max(a, b)` doesn't have any state, shared or otherwise so its thread safe.

Comment: What you exactly mean by "state"? You mean static method? Then all static methods become thread safe?! :-)

Comment: By state, I mean something which can change from one state to another. e.g. c = 0 and later it is c = 5.  In Java terms there has to be fields which are changed.

Comment: Or a database query, or filesystem access.  That counts as state, too.

Answer (score 14):

It's thread safe, why wouldn't it be? It has no state, there are no objects being modified when you call it. The method is just an if statement:

```
public static int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a >= b) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: What you exactly mean by "state"? You mean static method? Then all static methods become thread safe?! :-)

Answer (score 12):

`Math.max` is completely stateless, so it is totally thread safe.

Comment: What you exactly mean by "state"? You mean static method? Then all static methods become thread safe?! :-)

Comment: A method is _stateless_ if it will always, no matter what, return the same output on the same input.

Comment: @Louis: Not necessarily, a method can write to a file (which is not thread-safe) while returning 0 for any input.

Comment: Ew, point taken.  It's so much easier to describe in Haskell when you can't do anything stateful without marking it as in the IO monad...